# Two variables in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to add two variables to an string:

```
if code.alter_fehler == 'k' && code.alter_o.to_f <= 124
    @arr << "Bitte Kodierung überprüfen: Kode gilt überwiegend nur für Patienten in der
             Altersgruppe zwischen #{jahrtag(code.alter_u,'')} 
             und {jahrtag('',code.alter_o)}."
end
```

How you can see i call in the string two times the def jahrtag in the application controller:

```
 def jahrtag(zahlu,zahlo)
if (zahlu && zahlo) == '0' then return 'O Tagen' end
if zahlu == '1' then return '1 Jahr' end
if zahlu == '8' then return '8' end
if zahlu == '12' then return '12' end
if zahlu == '15' then return '15 Jahren' end
if zahlu == '18' then return '18 Jahre' end
if zahlu == '30' then return '30 Jahren' end
 end
```

But somehow, instead of getting the correct variable 'for example: 1 Jahr', my variables are printed out blank in the view! Does somebody know what i made wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you really using `"Bitte ..."` and not `'Bitte ...'`? I mean the quote sign.

Comment: @Bjoernsen how would single quotes help?

Comment: No, if you type something like '#{var}', you would get the string `#{var}` and not the value. It was my mistake, I did not read the question correct. I did not see `printed out BLANK in the view`, so it is not the problem of wrong quote signs. Sorry.

Comment: @Bjoernsen Got it, I misunderstood your first comment :)

Comment: What happens, if you add `puts zahlu` and `puts zahlo` in `def jahrtag`? Are the values correct? You can also add `puts zahlu.class`. It should be a String.

Comment: @user2724695 are you sure that `jahrtag` is working as expected? Its implementation looks odd.

Answer (score 4):

`und {jahrtag('',code.alter_o)}.` here you are missing the `#`

It should be `und #{jahrtag('',code.alter_o)}.`

Comment: oh thank you! How could i miss that!

Comment: But it still does not work

Comment: @user2724695 please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that none of the *if* statements are matching.  When execution of a method goes to the end of the method, the method returns the value of the last expression executed.  The last expression executed is an "if" where the condition is *falsy*; the result of an *if* with no *else* and a falsy condition is *nil*.

When ruby interpolates an expression into a string using the `#{...}` syntax, the expression is has `#to_s` called on it.  The result of `nil.to_s` is an empty string.

To fix this, add this as the last line of #jahrtag:

```
"#{zahlu} Jahren"
```

This way the function will always return a non-empty string, even when none of the *if* statements match.